# Does JIRA allow to check yesterdays tasks?

Tags: calendar, task, jira

I need to check which tasks were updated/created yesterday, the past week, the past month.
I would like to always use a web interface (only) where I could use a select calendar, insert dates, etc.

Is it possible to create filters with characters that have special meaning for JIRA to select last day, week, month or do I need to write some program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use JIRA and search for issues, you will find first an interface that allows to specify a lot of search options. One block of the options is called "Dates and Times".

[image]

When you go to the field called "From" and "To", and click on the date select button, a dialog is opened:

[image]

The result of that is then:

[image]

So you could add here the ranges you are interested in (for created, updated, due date and resolved) and store the resulting query as a filter. You may even store an URL that calls that filter, so by clicking the URL in your browser, the relevant search will be executed and the issues you have in focus will be shown.